# Check if .getJSON returned any data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm trying to use KnockOutJS and jQuery - is there any way I can check **allData** below, to see if it has returned anything?

If it hasn't, I want to hide a div on the screen:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#thankyou").hide(); // hide thank you box

$("#searchBtn").click(function () {

    $.getJSON("/api/searchapi/", function (allData) {
        sampleProductCategories = allData;  // I want to check if this has returned anything?
        if(!allData) { alert("nothing");}
        cart.RoomCategories(sampleProductCategories);
    });
 });
});
```

Firebug shows the empty JSON as:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your *"empty data"* is an empty array, just test it's length.

```
if (allData.length) {
    // we have data
}
else {
    // we don't have data
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kevin-b - I also used: ` if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(allData)){alert("empty");}`  And that worked too.  Thanks a lot, Mark

Comment: Don't use `jQuery.isEmptyObject(array)`. That function is meant to be used with plain objects, not arrays. It may work, but anyone reading your code will be confused about your intentions. `array.length` is the right way to test for an empty array.